# Design suggestion for an app which will wake up periodically and execute some long running tasks

Tags: google-app-engine, cron, google-cloud-messaging

I wish to develop a Java Appengine app. The basic task would be to do some tasks at some pre-configured intervals. The task itself could run for several hours and push messages to mobile devices (GCM). Some task timings could overlap.

**Q1**. Is Cron job the way to go? How do you set up cron job timings dynamically or have it read them from some config file? (since the timings of each job may change, sometimes). EDIT: This needs to work such that I can keep adding some "timings" to the config, dynamically (maybe through a Google spreadsheet or something and without having to redeploy the app)

**Q2**. I was reading about manual scaling, "*A manually-scaled instance can choose to handle /_ah/start and execute a program or script for many hours without returning an HTTP response code.*"
For my use-case, do I need automatic scaling or manual scaling? or should I use Backends?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any task that runs several hours on app engine [backend instances](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/backends) is the answer because frontend instances has 60seconds deadline before it kills any request.

Cron job by design is for tasks that are supposed to be done at specified intervals. See the [app engine cron documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron) on how to configure the intervals in cron.xml (you can't dynamically change the schedule).

From the requirements you've shared, I suggest you look into [Task queues](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/queue) which can be used along with Cron job to achieve what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, Task Queues look interesting. Ofcourse, the main problem is Q1. How do I have these tasks/crons start timings configurable without having to deploy the code everytime the job schedule changes?

Comment: @asim Since you haven't shared the scenarios much all I can say is that if you design your app carefully task queues and cron jobs are all you need. For eg., you can keep an entity in ndb which contains details of each task you added to the queue, their status. This way even if the cron job gets called every x whatever interval it doesn't necessarily have to run the actual process unless the conditions in the entity allows it to.

Comment: Thanks appreciate your patience and follow up. A typical scenario could be say start of a Football tournament or individual games. I would just need to wake up and send a message to the user's mobile at the start of the game. So polling as you described is one way, but I guess it would be inefficient (since I would wake up every x mins, but although the next event could really be weeks apart). Is there any other alternative?

Comment: For the same scenario, you could have the cron job running very one hour but have it process data and send a message only if there's anything available to send to the user, so it really doesn't matter how much interval is there between events. 

If this answers your question, please mark this answer :)